# NX run-commands forward multiple arguments with same name

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl, nx.dev

I'm trying to pass multiple arguments with same name with run-commands, for example:
`nx run project:build --define foo=123 --define bar=456`

It seems nx will collapse the argument and forwarding only 1 argument to the underlying command, for example:
`mvn package --define=foo=123,bar=456`

Is there a way to disable this behavior so the underlying command will receive arguments as is? like
`mvn package --define foo=123 --define bar=456`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed in v15, parameters are no longer 'merged' in this way